# Cast XML to money

Tags: sql-server, xml, casting, currency

I have some XML data that I need to add up as currency. Every conversion I try gets the error

> Explicit conversion from data type xml to ____ is not allowed.

Here's a simple example, containing several failed attempts.

```
DECLARE @xmlstuff xml

SET @xmlstuff = '3'

SELECT 
   CAST (@xmlstuff AS varchar(80)) as worksButDontCare,
   --CAST (@xmlstuff AS MONEY) as dollars, -- Explicit conversion from data type xml to money is not allowed.
   --CAST (@xmlstuff AS NUMERIC) as number, -- Explicit conversion from data type xml to numeric is not allowed.
   --CONVERT (decimal(18,2),@xmlstuff ) AS cd1_feeAmount, -- Explicit conversion from data type xml to decimal is not allowed.
```

Comment: How did you get the value `3` as XML to begin with? Whatever technique you used should have returned it as `MONEY` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that I found is to convert to varchar as an intermediate step.

```
CAST ((CAST (@xmlstuff AS varchar(80))) AS MONEY)  AS xmlToVarcharToMoney
```

Answer (score 2):

TSQL does not allow for direct conversion from xml to any numeric type.

So, as [@incircuitous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279432/4905310) pointed, you will have to convert first to text, and then to Money

For more information about TSQL data type conversion, [look for the big table on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The conversion table in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) is indeed useful for reference, +1 for [@GabrielRainha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4905310/gabriel-rainha).

To get value out of XML data type I would recommend to look into XML specific methods, namely [`value()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) for this particular case :

```
DECLARE @xmlstuff xml
SET @xmlstuff = '3'

SELECT @xmlstuff.value('.', 'money') as dollars
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/791)**

The 2nd parameter of `value()` is the data type of return value. And the first parameter is XQuery expression to locate the value within XML structure. Assuming you don't have any structure in the XML -simply the value, because of which you expect it to be convertible directly using `CAST`-, you can always pass `.` as the 1st parameter.